# In Excel how can I transpose multiple rows into a single column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, transpose

I have rows of data all of equal length, e.g. A1:A5, B1:B5, C1:C5, etc. I want to put these into a single column, e.g. D1:D5, D6:D10, D11:D15, etc. There are no headers or row identifiers.
I think that using INDIRECT with a combination of ROW and COLUMN values should work, but I can't seem to find the right combo.

Comment: It would have been better to clean up your original question.  However, rather than double posting, please delete the [first question](http://superuser.com/questions/1039107/convert-rows-of-data-into-a-single-column).  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some more context?  For example, you could just select and drag three short ranges.  Or, you could just use cell references (D1: =A1; drag down a few rows, then D6: =B1, etc.).  Why do you need to get fancy with a function?  Have you looked at using OFFSET?  Recommending a specific solution really depends on the requirements of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: **A1:A5** is a column and not a row.

Answer (score 2):

With data in **A1** through **C5**, in **D1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,3))
```

and copy down.  This will *transpose* the data into a single column:

[image]

It is equally easy to place the data into a single column without transposition.

Answer (score 1):

This will ignore column headers and will not delete the data from the original cells. Depending on your worksheet, you may need to change the values for the columns.

```
Sub Macro1()

  Const firstRowWithData = 2 ' assumes labels in row 1
  Dim anyWS As Worksheet
  Dim copyRange As Range
  Dim CP As Integer

  For Each anyWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For CP = Range("B1").Column To Range("D1").Column
      Set copyRange = anyWS.Range(anyWS.Cells(2, CP).Address & ":" & _
       anyWS.Cells(Rows.Count, CP).End(xlUp).Address)
      copyRange.Copy anyWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next
  Next

End Sub
```

before

```
A Header    B Header    C Header
a           b           c
a           b           c
a           b           c
```

after

```
A Header    B Header    C Header
a           b           c
a           b           c
a           b           c
b       
b       
b       
c       
c       
c
```

Then manually delete the original columns.