# Excel - Combine range to column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to combine a range of cells (shown in the screenshot) into a singe column while ignoring blank cells.

[image: Screenshot]

The order does not matter, the column should look something like this:

- pr
- pf
- pth
- psz
- …

(Without the bullet points of course.)

The final single column should contain no blank cells.

Please note that I am using an iPad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Excel how can I transpose multiple rows into a single column?](https://superuser.com/questions/1039542/in-excel-how-can-i-transpose-multiple-rows-into-a-single-column)

Comment: Welcome! Does your iPad have Word? If you select and copy all the data in the original table, then paste it into Word as RTF, you will get a text table. This table is easy to convert to text with a "paragraph mark" delimiter - you'll get all the values in one column with empty rows in place of empty cells. It's easy to get rid of gaps by searching for ^p^p and replacing with ^p (repeat Replace All a few times). Copy the result and paste it into Excel. (Spaces can also be removed after pasting into Excel - just sort this column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Excel 365, the new function =TOCOL(Range, Ignore) does exactly that. To leave out empty values, use `=TOCOL(Range, 1)`.